# Logical help to get arranged data from python lists?

Tags: python

I have an problem to solve but i am getting confused on how to resolve it
I have two list with some data corresponding to each other.

```
For ex:
A a1
A a2
A a3
B b1
B b2
B a1
A c1
A c2
C c1
C c2
C c3
C c4
D b1
```

I want to solve above problem like :-

```
ID Count Data
A    3    a1,a2,a3
B    2    b1 b2
B    1    a1
A    1    c1
A    1    c1
C    4    c1, c2, c3, c4
D    1    b1
```

Comment: Please show us some *concrete* code

Comment: you have them in two seperate list?

Comment: are these strings in the list? is the output a list of strings or a list of lists? have you tried anything that we can debug and help with? or do you just want us to write your program for you?

Comment: Yeas, both of them in problem are separate list and I want the solution like ID's in list and Data in list as well just comma separated will also do and list of list is also appreciated

Comment: Even then there seems no logic? Why did this two `A    1    c1
A    1    c1` are on two separate rows. and why `B    2    b1 b2
B    1    a1` on two seperate rows. There seems to be no logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming the `A 1 c1 A 1 c1` was a typo because `A c1` only appears once in the example dataset.

Setup:

```
l1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D']
l2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'a1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'b1']
```

Here's one way that creates a dict whose keys are the elements in l1 + the first character in l2, and whose values are lists containing all the elements in l2 that create the same key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

for x1,x2 in zip(l1, l2):
    dd[x1 + x2[0]].append(x2)

ids = []
counts = []
data = []

print('ID,Count,Data')
for k,v in dd.items():
    ids.append(k[0])
    counts.append(len(v))
    data.append(v)
    print('{},{},{}'.format(k[0], len(v), v))
```

Prints:

```
ID,Count,Data
A,3,['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
B,2,['b1', 'b2']
B,1,['a1']
A,2,['c1', 'c2']
C,4,['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
D,1,['b1']
```

Here is another way using pandas. Its a similar approach because it still uses the IDs from l1 and the first characters of the elements in l2 to create groups.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(ID=ID, Data=Data, FirstChar=Data[0]) 
                   for ID,Data in zip(l1, l2)])

result = df.groupby(['ID', 'FirstChar']).Data.apply(list)
result = result.reset_index('FirstChar', drop=True).reset_index('ID')
result['Count'] = result.Data.apply(len)

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
  ID              Data  Count
0  A      [a1, a2, a3]      3
1  A          [c1, c2]      2
2  B              [a1]      1
3  B          [b1, b2]      2
4  C  [c1, c2, c3, c4]      4
5  D              [b1]      1
```

Comment: Thank you @Jay, this was it and clean.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose ID's are in list `ID` and a1, b2, c3, etc. in `values` list. Then you can create a nested dictionary:

```
d = {}
for id, val in zip(ID, values):
    stuff = d.get(id, {}) #if no value with key 'id' found, returns {}
    try:
        stuff['count'] += 1
    except KeyError:
        stuff['count'] = 1

    try:
        stuff['values'].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        stuff['values'] = [val]

    d[id] = stuff

print("ID\tCount\tValues"
for key in d:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (key, d[key]['count'], d[key]['values']))
```

This would produce the desired output.

Comment: I am getting compile time error at stuff.get)'count line
can't assign to function call
can't assign to function call
d.get Found at: HMI_AT.src.general

stuff = d.get(id, {}) #if no value with key 'id' found, returns {}

Comment: @PawankumarDubey I'm not able to understand which line. stuff.get('count') or stuff.get(id)?

Comment: stuff.get('count')

Comment: @PawankumarDubey Thanks for pointing out the error. I've modified the code accordingly. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to what you want,

But assuming that if you have two lists,

```
a =['A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','C','C','C','C','D']
b=['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','a1','c1','c2','c1','c2','c3','c4','b1']
```

You want the output to be something like this,

```
key(ID) count data(Values for key)
A        5    ['a1','a2','a3','a1','c1']
```

This must be the logical solution for your problem (else mention it more clearly...assuming you want to do that. I would suggest using `dict()` or dictionaries.

Here is the code:

```
a =['A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','C','C','C','C','D']
b=['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','a1','c1','c2','c1','c2','c3','c4','b1']

my_dict = {}

print("ID ,count, Data")
fin_list = list(zip(a,b))
for item in fin_list:
    my_dict.setdefault(item[0],[]).append(item[1])

for key in my_dict:
    print("{0},{1},{2}".format(key,len(my_dict[key]),my_dict[key]))
```

output:

```
ID , count, Data
A,5,['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c1', 'c2']
C,4,['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
D,1,['b1']
B,3,['b1', 'b2', 'a1']
```

So what happens is that, in `fin_list = list(zip(a,b))` This just zips (i.e pairs each item from both lists correspondingly)

Use `your_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)` just appends multiple values to your `key` in the dict. (or creates a new key if key not present)

```
my_dict.setdefault(item[0],[]).append(item[1])
```